# How to click only em tag text on JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a click event at the front.

Click Tuesday and Thursday to activate the click function.

But I want to make it work only when I click two or four.

Please refer to the code below.

```
<li class="swiper">
  <span style="" class="Day">
    화<em date="2022-08-02" class="on">2</em>
  </span>
</li>
    
<li class="swiper">
  <span style="" class="Day">
    목<em date="2022-08-04">4</em>
  </span>
</li>
```

**js click code (i try)**

```
       $("li > span > em").click(function () {
            $("li > span > em").removeClass("on");
            $(this).addClass("on");
})
```

What should I do?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. How does it _not work_? What do you see happen vs what do you expect to happen? Do you have any errors reported in your console?

Comment: @phil Please understand that I can't upload the image and I can't express it in pictures.

Comment: This click event works, but I only want it to work when I click em text.

Comment: However, the code is wrapped in the span tag, so a click event applies to the span when pressed anywhere.

Comment: `How can I click only the em text value?`

Comment: _"I can't upload the image"_... I didn't ask you to and would actually prefer that you didn't. Please [edit] your question to explain in as simple terms as possible how this isn't working because as far as I can tell, it works just fine

Comment: If I click on the `2` or `4`, it changes the `on` class. If I click on anything else like `화` or `목`, nothing happens as expected

Comment: I cannot reproduce any issue with your code ~ https://jsfiddle.net/L7ey9anw/

Comment: "*However, the code is wrapped in the span tag, so a click event applies to the span*" - there's no click event on the `span` in the *code provided* - do you have another event not shown?  The event in the question will *not* fire when clicking outside the `em`.   It sounds like you have another event that you've not shown.  In which case, add `return false;` to your `$("li > span > em").click(function () {` (as the last line) or add event and add event. stopPropagation() see [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.Day', function(){})
```

Comment: this function not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a solution for you ! it's the **stopPropagation()** method. it prevents propagation of the same event from being called.
***Propagation*** means bubbling up to parent elements or capturing down to child elements.

Try this out :

```
$(" li > span > em").click(function (e) {
    alert('em CLICKED');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("li > span").click(function (e) {
    alert('span CLICKED');
    $("li > span > em").removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working. You can check by adding alert or console.log inside the click callback function.

```
$("li > span > em").click(function () {
  alert('hello');
  $("li > span > em").removeClass("on");
  $(this).addClass("on");
})
```

Comment: The code will work in its original.

But what I want is that the click event on text Tuesday Thursday doesn't work on the span

I want to make it `work only when I click em tag text(2,4)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).